# end program using keypress in visual basic

Tags: vb6, keypress

I want to end program in visual basic using keypress procedure. I use this code but every time i press a key it doesn't end the program.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
End
End Sub
```

I write this and it works :

```
Private Sub Form_DblClick()
End
End Sub
```

but pressing doesnt work

Comment: Try Environment.Exit(0) - where 0 is the exit code to report back if anything is looking at it.  Typically, 0 means no error, anything else means something went wrong.

Comment: @Aaron that applies to vb.net, not vb6

Comment: Maybe tag vb6 next time.

Comment: but why it works in Form_DblClick()?

Comment: I am using visual basic 2006

Comment: You want the VB.Net tag then.

Comment: Visual Basic 2006?  Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To intercept keypresses from anywhere on the form, set the Form property KeyPreview to True. 
You can set this at runtime with `Me.KeyPreview = True` in the Form's Initialize  or Main method.

Once you are capturing all keystrokes, use System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit() within the method to end the program. Check this[enter link description here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx) out for more info on exiting the application.

Comment: Question is tagged VB6; the 2nd paragraph of your answer relates to vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

You've put your code in the Form KeyPress event. If the form has any controls on it, the active control gets the event. The form only sees the KeyPress event when you set `KeyPreview` = True. In the Form properties try setting the KeyPreview to True, then test it again.[image]